# Mysql group rows by date into 4 seasons + year

Tags: mysql

At the moment I am grouping the news into month+year but we dont have enough news articles. So instead would like to group them by season: summer, spring, autumn or winter + year

So instead of:

- January 2013
- March 2013
- April 2013

It would be:

- Summer 2013
- Spring 2013

Monthly archieve

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(news_date) AS MONTH,
       YEAR(news_date) AS YEAR,
       COUNT(news_id) AS COUNT
FROM news
WHERE news_type = 'NEWS'
  AND news_status = 'ENABLED'
GROUP BY CONCAT(MONTH(news_date), ' ', YEAR(news_date))
ORDER BY news_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT case when MONTH(news_date) between 3 and 5 then 'Spring',
            when MONTH(news_date) between 6 and 8 then 'Summer',
            when MONTH(news_date) between 9 and 11 then 'Autum',
            when MONTH(news_date) >= 12 and MONTH(news_date) <= 2 then 'Winter'
       end AS Period,
       YEAR(news_date) AS YEAR,
       COUNT(news_id) AS COUNT
FROM news
WHERE news_type = 'NEWS' AND news_status = 'ENABLED'
GROUP BY YEAR(news_date), Period
ORDER BY news_date DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(news_date) IN (12, 1, 2) THEN 'Winter'
            WHEN MONTH(news_date) IN (3, 4, 5) THEN 'Spring'
            WHEN MONTH(news_date) IN (6, 7, 8) THEN 'Summer'
       ELSE 'Fall' END AS Season,
       YEAR(news_date) AS YEAR,
       COUNT(news_id) AS COUNT
FROM news
WHERE news_type = 'NEWS'
  AND news_status = 'ENABLED'
GROUP BY YEAR(news_date), Season
ORDER BY news_date DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

To get numeric seasons (Winter as 0 through to Autumn as 3), try the more compact:

```
SELECT quantity, FLOOR((MONTH(date_field) % 12)/3) as season
FROM `tbl`
GROUP BY season
```

Answer (score 0):

use CASE statement like below in your query

```
CASE WHEN MONTH(news_date) = 1 or MONTH(news_date) = 2 or MONTH(news_date) = 3 
     THEN CONCAT('SPRING ' , YEAR(news_date) ) 
     WHEN MONTH(news_date) = 4 or MONTH(news_date) = 5 or MONTH(news_date) = 6 
     THEN CONCAT('SUMMER ' , YEAR(news_date) ) 
     WHEN MONTH(news_date) = 7 or MONTH(news_date) = 8 or MONTH(news_date) = 9 
     THEN CONCAT('AUTUMN ' , YEAR(news_date) ) 
     WHEN MONTH(news_date) = 10 or MONTH(news_date) = 11 or MONTH(news_date) = 12 
     THEN CONCAT('WINTER ' , YEAR(news_date) )
```